# python dataframe fill up

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

```
     1   
0   an     
1   df     
2   0       
3   sdg    
4   gd     
5   dg     
6   0       
7   dc     
8   0      
9   dcd    
10  ds      
11  1    
12  sdg  
13  ds   
14  1    
15  sd   
16  sg   
17  2    
18  dsg  
19  sdg  
20  dfg  
21  2
```

I want to ask how to use the above dataframe to generate the following  dataframe, according to the first column to generate second column. (just like fill up in excel, but many times)

```
     1   2
0   an   0  
1   df   0  
2   0    0   
3   sdg  0  
4   gd   0  
5   dg   0  
6   0    0   
7   dc   0  
8   0    0  
9   dcd  1  
10  ds   1   
11  1    1
12  sdg  1
13  ds   1
14  1    1
15  sd   2
16  sg   2
17  2    2
18  dsg  2
19  sdg  2
20  dfg  2
21  2    2
```

Here's just some example, the maximum number in the second column is 520, and the number in the second column is consecutive and in order.

Comment: Sure you can. what do you want to generate? Please update your question.

Comment: Sorry it's my fault, I have tried to update it, please let me know if it's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your break points are the numbers and you want to fill the values for the strings:

```
df[2] = pd.to_numeric(df[1], errors='coerce').bfill().astype('int')

df
Out: 
      1  2
0    an  0
1    df  0
2     0  0
3   sdg  0
4    gd  0
5    dg  0
6     0  0
7    dc  0
8     0  0
9   dcd  1
10   ds  1
11    1  1
12  sdg  1
13   ds  1
14    1  1
15   sd  2
16   sg  2
17    2  2
18  dsg  2
19  sdg  2
20  dfg  2
21    2  2
```

Comment: thank you! I tried the code, there's an error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. I don't know why, thanks!

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-160-1ea5817e71c6> in <module>()
----> 1 data['c'] = pd.to_numeric(data['a'], errors='coerce').bfill().astype('int')

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: It seems `data`  is a list, not a DataFrame. Did you convert it to a DataFrame like the one you showed in the OP?